# MySQL to MySQLi Query issue when joining arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to convert some MYSQL querys to MYSQLI, but I'm having an issue, below is part of the script I am having issues with, the script turn a query into csv:

```
$columns = (($___mysqli_tmp = mysqli_num_fields($result)) ? $___mysqli_tmp : false); 

// Build a header row using the mysql field names 

$rowe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$acolumns = array_keys($rowe);
$csvstring = '"=""' . implode('""","=""', $acolumns) . '"""';
$header_row = $csvstring; 

// Below was used for MySQL, Above was added for MySQLi
//$header_row = '';
//for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
//  $column_title = $file["csv_contain"] . stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i)) . $file["csv_contain"];
//  $column_title .= ($i < $columns-1) ? $file["csv_separate"] : '';
//  $header_row .= $column_title;
//  } 
$csv_file .= $header_row . $file["csv_end_row"]; // add header row to CSV file 

// Build the data rows by walking through the results array one row at a time 
$data_rows = ''; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) { 
    // clean up the data; strip slashes; replace double quotes with two single quotes 
    $data_rows .= $file["csv_contain"] .$file["csv_equ"] .$file["csv_contain"] .$file["csv_contain"] . preg_replace('/'.$file["csv_contain"].'/', $file["csv_contain"].$file["csv_contain"], stripslashes($row[$i])) . $file["csv_contain"] .$file["csv_contain"] .$file["csv_contain"];
    $data_rows .= ($i < $columns-1) ? $file["csv_separate"] : ''; 
  } 
  $data_rows .= $this->csv_end_row; // add data row to CSV file 
} 
$csv_file .= $data_rows; // add the data rows to CSV file 

if ($this->debugFlag) { 
  echo "Step 4 (repeats for each attachment): CSV file built. \n\n"; 
} 

// Return the completed file 
return $csv_file;
```

The problem I am having is when building a header row for the column titles mysqli doesn't use field_names so I am fetching the column titles by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and then `implode()` the array, adding the `,`'s etc for the csv.

This works but when I produce the csv I am deleting the first data row when the header is active, when I remove my header part of the script and leave the header as null I get all data rows and a blank header (As expected).

So I must be missing something when joining my header to array to the `$csv_file`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks

Ben

Comment: Any reason you can't use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputscsv)?

Comment: Only because the code I am using emails the csv file automaticaly and I thought it would be easier to change this code than to start again

Comment: Writing your own CSV formatter is error prone and [duplicates existing functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If you need the data in a string, you can still use `fgetcsv` by writing to either a [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) stream (saving the reult to a stream with `stream_get_contents`) or a [string stream](http://code.google.com/p/phpstringstream/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third alternative is to refactor the loop body as a function, then also call this function on the first row before entering the loop. You can use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv) as this function.

```
$csv_stream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($csv_stream, array_keys($row));

    fputcsv($csv_stream, $row);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        fputcsv($csv_stream, $row);
    }

    fseek($csv_stream, 0);
}
$csv_data = stream_get_contents($csv_stream);
if ($this->debugFlag) { 
  echo "Step 4 (repeats for each attachment): CSV file built. \n\n"; 
} 

// Return the completed file
return $csv_data;
```

As this basically does the same thing as a `do ... while` loop, which would make more sense to use. I bring up this alternative to present the loop body refactoring technique, which can be used when a different kind of loop doesn't make sense.

Best of all would be to use both `mysqli_result::fetch_fields` and `fputcsv`

```
$csv_stream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

$fields = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach ($fields as &$field) {
    $field = $field->name;
}
fputcsv($csv_stream, $fields);

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    fputcsv($csv_stream, $row);
}

fseek($csv_stream, 0);
$csv_data = stream_get_contents($csv_stream);
if ($this->debugFlag) { 
  echo "Step 4 (repeats for each attachment): CSV file built. \n\n"; 
} 

// Return the completed file
return $csv_data;
```

If you can require that PHP be at least version 5.3, you can replace the `foreach` that generates the header line with a call to `array_map`. There admittedly isn't much advantage to this, I just find the functional approach more interesting.

```
fputcsv($csv_stream, 
        array_map(function($field) {return $field->name}, 
                  $result->fetch_fields()));
```

Comment: Hi, Your second option gave me the error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in class.email-query-csv.php on line 277 (line 277 : foreach ($fields as &$field) {) Your first option kind of worked, gave me the field names and the data rows, but the data rows were all over the place, the 1st data row was perfect but then the ones after that repeated each field data twice (duplicating them) so not sure what has happened there?

Comment: Sorry line 277 is: $field = $field['name'];

Comment: `mysqli_result::fetch_fields` returns an array of objects, not an array of arrays as I had first thought, so you have to use the property access operator (`->`) rather than array index operator (`[]`). The duplicate fields were due to `mysqli_result::fetch_array`'s default mode of [`MYSQLI_BOTH`](http://php.net/mysqli.constants). I'm normally a PDO man. See update (changed line 277 to `$field = $field->name;` and `fetch_array` to `fetch_row`).

Answer (score 0):

As you observe, you're using the first row to obtain the field names but then not using the data from the row. Evidently, you need to change your code so that you get both of those things.

There are a number of ways you might do this. The most appropriate one is to use `mysqli_fetch_fields()` instead to get the field metadata from the result object.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Alternatively, you could make the loop lower down in the code a `do... while` instead of a `while`.

Comment: The field names are being used $header_row = $csvstring; and do show up in the csv, but the problem seems to be that the header is over writing the first row of data from the $data_rows so in the csv I get my header (field names) but loose the first row of data.

Comment: @Ben: Hammerite has it correct. You're not using the values from `$rowe`; you're never writing the values from the first row to $csv_file.

Comment: How come if I'm not using the values from $rowe the values from $rowe show in my outputted csv file? I'm confused!

Comment: You are using `$rowe` to find out the names of the fields. However, `$rowe` is a row from the resultset (the first row, the one retrieved by your first call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`) and you are not using that data. Any of the rows from the resultset could be used to find the names of the fields; there is nothing special about the first row. It happens that you are using the first row to get column metadata but you aren't using the actual data in that row.

Comment: @Hammerite ahhhh ok I get what you are saying, sorry I'm not so good at this stuff. I've sorted it but I would think a messy way. I've moved the $rowe part down the code and called a new query for that part, then joined it. that seems to have worked.